# Want to find exact 5 strings sentences

Tags: regex

I want to search a string which contains a maximum of 5 words.

I.e.it should match: 
`abc def ghi jkl mno`

but not
`abc def ghi jkl mno pqr`

as it has more than 5 words.

I have written this regex:

```
(([A-Za-z]+)( [A-Za-z]+){1,4})
```

but it also matches on `abc def ghi jkl mno`.

Comment: Sorry, *I want to search **the string** which have maximum **5 strings*** makes it rather unclear. What do you mean?

Comment: means sentence with upto five strin not more than five

Comment: Maybe 5 **words consisting of ASCII letters**? Please note that regex questions require every minute detail on the input strings.

Comment: You say *exact* 5 "strings", but are using a limiting quantifier `{1,4}` (so your regex only matches 2 to 5 letter chunks separated with a whitespace). That is again unclear. Try `^[A-Za-z]+( +[A-Za-z]+){0,4}$`, it will match strings with 1 to 5 ASCII letter chunks separated with 1+ spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match only strings containing 5 words or less, i.e. not any five words in a row, you also need to add anchoring to the beginning and end of the string:

```
^((?:\w+ ?){1,5})$
```

#### Example

https://regex101.com/r/pN9nQ0/1

Comment: @PradipPatel if this solves the issue, please mark as answered.